# How to compare the contents of two resource files (*.res)?

Tags: c#, vb6

I am working on a vb project which uses a resource file (*.res) to map between two values.

Now I need to compare two resource files (existing one and the edited one), I have "Beyond Compare" and "Win-Merge" software to compare ..
but the RES file gets opened only in Visual Studio and the contents of the RES file can't be copied all at once ..
and as it uses some script (or encryption) on its contents .. it can't be opened with any other editors

now because of which I have to make a manual comparison which is hectic task .. file size is too big .. the alternate was to use file compare software where as they don't support this extension of file ..

Can you please help me with extraction of the contents of the file?

Comment: I thought, its a programming related question so posted in SO, if you think it belongs to SU or somewhere else .. please help to migrate.

Comment: There's an application (Resource Hacker, you can get it [here](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)) that will let you manipulate and extract the contents of the RES file into RC files (and ICO, etc.). You can use it as a command line tool too.

Comment: @ssarabando, I used ResEdit32 (a freeware) to convert to RC,
That could do .. as rc files can be edited using notepad (even better notepad++) ..

Thanks for the response anyways :)

Comment: WinMerge has been able to compare binary files for a few years, which is enough to see if they're the same. You can also easily see what changes have been made to textual resurces (and to a lesser extent, string tables)

Comment: Well. If there are minor changes then fine, but my requirements usually have greater number of changes. I don't feel secure with assumptions and manual works. Thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download a resource editor (like [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/)) and convert it to a resource script (`.rc`) file.

A resource script is as good as a text file, can be copied and edited using notepad

Two files can be directly compared in beyond compare.